# JSF - Web.xml file not found in Web Context

Tags: eclipse, jsf

I am having trouble getting my web.xml to recognize a welcome/login file.

The following lines produce something along the lines of "references to 'filename' that does not exist in web content"

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/login.html</form-error-page>
</form-login-config>
```

Both login.html and index.xhtml exist in ProjectRoot/WebContent

What allows Eclipse, and I assume JSF, to recognize a file in the WebContent folder?

Here is the full web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>MyApp</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>bluesky</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>All</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>MyLDAP</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/login.html</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

Comment: When does that message appear? At development time? At runtime? Where does it appear?

Comment: Intellisense, though it may affect more than just that. No explicit console messages appear regarding it, but connecting to localhost:8080/MyApp does not redirect to the welcome page.

Comment: What happens instead, both in the browser and server log?

Comment: Accessing the root, localhost:8080/MyApp, I get 'Forbidden'. Accessing localhost:8080/MyApp/index.xhtml and localhost:8080/MyApp/login.html yield 'Not Found'. No console messages, one server log: "[org.jboss.security] (default task-6) PBOX00354: Setting security roles ThreadLocal: null".